# Set a NSString from a passed id

Tags: ios, nsstring, master-detail

I have an ios app that uses the master detail template, the master view passes the id of an NSString to a subview for the subview to display in a textview that the user can edit. What i want to do is, when the button is pressed to return from the subview to the master view, set the text of the NSString that was passed in to whatever the user changed it to. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer to this is don't pass a string to the detail view. Pass a model. There must be some overlying model to the data between the master and the detail. Pass the model, update the model in the detail, then when you go back to the master, the changes in the model will automatically be reflected in the master.

Here is an example assume that master contains a array of models which correspond to the cells of the tableView. Then, in the detail view, when you change self.model.myString the master view will be updated also.

```
@interface MySimpleModel
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *myString;
@end
```

…

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"To Detail From Master"])
    {
        // Get which indexPath of the cell in the master to use.
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell];

        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        DetailViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        vc.model = (MySimpleModel *)[self.models objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Comment: Im rather new to objective-c, by model, do you mean class? or is that something different?

Comment: @whyrusleeping You might want to read up on the MVC pattern ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller )-- it's virtually enforced in iOS anyways, so you SHOULD be familiar with it by now.  And yes, he meant you should be passing a class rather than just the string.